# Passing param in ngOnInit in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to trigger a function that has a parameter in it like `trigger(id)` in `ngOnInit`?

I have a function that I want to trigger on `(click)` event as well as in `ngOnInit` so when the page first load it triggers basically the same function because it calls to the same API end-point.

function to be triggered in `ngOnInit`

```
 getOrdersFromOrigin(id: number): void {
   ...
}
```

so in `ngOnInit` would be something like this maybe? its showing an error "Cannot find name 'id'"

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrdersFromOrigin(id);
  }
```

Id is coming from my `ngFor`, its an `Id` of an item which I want to click `(click)="getOrdersFromOrigin(id)"`

Comment: `id` is part of the scope of `getOrdersFromOrigin()` so it would not be declared in the scope of `ngInInit()`. Unless you know which id to call you can't do it, id need to be set or a value need to be used instead.

Comment: if id in not suppilied to the function it will throw error. You need to handle that in you function if id is not defined or present do something. Because in ngOnInit id might not be available as you are not triggering the click from the view/ its not user triggered. Pass some default value for that if not defined.

Comment: no I don't know which id i'm going to be clicking, as the ids are coming from `ngFor` and just passing the `item.id` in my function in `(click)` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle it if its in route like param. For example if you are editing some record in table by clicking edit button then your app navigate to edit form you can handle it like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        this.getOrdersFromOrigin(id);
    });
}

getOrdersFromOrigin(id: number){
//some code
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I need but putting the `getOrdersFromOrigin(id)` outside the `forEach` otherwise it'd iterate every time.

Answer (score 0):

The param id is in getOrdersFromOrigin(), so it would **not work** in the **scope of ngOnInit()**, my suggestion is that you can declare a property **id** and marked it as **@Input()**. then you can use it outside. The codes is below:

```
export class SameComponent implement OnInit {
   @Input() id:number=0; //initialize
    getOrdersFromOrigin(id: number): void {
    ...
  }
  ngOnInit() {   this.getOrdersFromOrigin(id);}
}
```

Comment: But then this will always take the `id=0` in the put as default value?